# Signalr - The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format

Tags: signalr, nlb

I'm using signalr in my application to notify user how the proccess is doing. When i test it in localhost, everything works well, but when I deploy the same code in production i get the error bellow:

The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.

My production enviroment is configurated with NLB (Network Load Balance) of windows server. This can cause the intermittent problem? Are there a solution to resolve it?

Thaks

Comment: Please show us the any part of code that may be related as any usage of ConnectionId

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your settings in the balancing:

> Normally, when running ASP.NET in a load balanced environment in a
>   webfarm, you make the machine keys the same on all servers so when
>   clients flip flop between machines, they encryption and signing work
>   consistently in your farm.
>   https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2292